# Getting 404 error while trying to call a service

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment

I am facing a weird issue in my project. 
After a deployment of a particular service (**myServices**) in a remote server I am trying to open `http://serverIp:port/myServices/` and I am getting 404.

Also, I tried to open a sample html (test.html) directly by hitting `http://serverIp:port/myServices/test.html` and then also I got same error. The location 
of test.html is `webapps\myServices\test.html`.
I verified that the service is running in the correct port. In fact, while I am trying to hit that service from our application its working fine.
I am facing issue only if I try to hit that service direclty. 
Please help me resolving this issue.

We are using Tomcat 8 and Java 1.8

Thanks.

Comment: `myService` may not deployed properly. Check the catalina.out and locahost.log files for errors.

Answer (score 0):

The service(or the application) may not be bound to the public ip, it may just be bound to localhost and hence if the other application is also running on the same machine - it will not have any issues in calling the service.

Comment: Thanks. can u please explain "not bound to the public ip" ?